# Euler project #5 recursion?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, recursion, callstack

I tried to solve the fifth project Euler problem and I wrote the following function to return the j:s that are divisible by some i. This is the function:

```js
function smallest(x,j){
debugger
  if (x >= j) {
    console.log("done")
  }else {
    for (var i = 2; i <= 20; i++) {
      if (j%i != 0) {
        smallest(x+1,j)
      }else {
        console.log(j,i)
      }
    }
  }
}

smallest(1,1000)
```

note: since x is always going start at 1, it didn't have be one of the function-arguments, it could have been defined earlier as a variable. I chose to write it as an parameter because it is then visible in the debugger process.

Anyways, when called upon, as you can see I ran a debugger in the start of the definition of the function. When the debugger runs through the function when called upon (I obviously called the function later) for small values of j and i (I manually reduced i:s maximum values) it runs through as it should but at the very end, when it is completely done, x suddenly changes to j-1. It basically adapts somehow to the requirements of j. Why is this happening? This is causing the callstack to max out and the function is thus not executable. I'm figuring there shouldn't be any more problems after x has exceeded j and this should not be a problem. For example, I tried to execute the function with some values that eventually gave an output of "done" (js:4). This output is only given when x is larger than j and if it isn't, it should execute other actions. Since there is no recursion before the "else" and this function is not called and executed in some sort of loop, I should only expect 1 console.log("done") to be executed. Why do I get more than 1?

small example of what is happening when smallest(1,5) with i's max value =

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? I don't know what the `s` or colon means in `return the j:s that are divisible by some i`. (do you mean `j's`, like plural `j`?)

Comment: I meant it like j in plural.

Comment: And what is "the fifth project Euler problem"? You need to give a clear definition of the problem stated here.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a poor choice for this problem. The solution is a 9-digit number well beyond the stack capacity, so even after resolving the logic issues, recursion is still going to fail.

The given code seems to be conflating the duties of the inner and outer loops and mixing up `x` (the candidate number we want to test) and `j` (the termination point/base case).

Issues include:

- Identical recursive calls are being spawned for *every* non-divisible number less than 20. This is an exponential complexity explosion and explains why you're seeing multiple "done"s printed. Use `break` after the recursive call to prevent this.
- Since `j` is always the same in every recursive function call, `j % i != 0` just runs the same comparisons over and over in every frame, ignoring `x`.
- Even if `x` was used instead of `j`, remember that a candidate is only accepted when it's divisible by *every* number from 1 to 20, not *any*.
- `smallest(j+1,j)` should not use `j` (which is supposed to be the termination point) as the first argument. `smallest(x + 1, j)` was probably the intent. Giving `j` a better name like `endpoint` would eliminate this bug.
- Function should be pure and not produce [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) like printing. Return values and let the caller do what they wish with them.

---

I think breaking the problem down into two distinct steps can help clarify the approach.

First, write a function to determine if a number is divisible by every number from 1 to `k`. This amounts to writing a loop:

```
const divisibleByAllBelowK = (n, k) => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
    if (n % i !== 0) return false;
  }

  return true;
};
```

Armed with that function, count upwards from 1 in an outer loop until we locate the first candidate number that passes the divisibility test.

```js
const divisibleByAllBelowK = (n, k) => {
  for (let i = 2; i <= k; i++) {
    if (n % i !== 0) return false;
  }

  return true;
};

for (var i = 1; !divisibleByAllBelowK(i, 10); i++);

console.log(i);
```

If you must use recursion, use it for the up-to-`k` divisibility test since `k` is given to be small:

```js
const divisibleByAllBelowK = (n, k) =>
  k < 2 ? true : n % k === 0 && divisibleByAllBelowK(n, k - 1)
;

for (var i = 1; !divisibleByAllBelowK(i, 10); i++);

console.log(i);
```

This shaves a few lines but isn't a good general solution. If `k` is too large, the stack will blow, and the function call overhead gunks up the works. Instead of returning instantly as soon as a failing case is found, the entire stack needs to unwind. Worse yet, it's not any more intuitive written recursively than iteratively, so there's really no advantage to this.

These brute force approaches are slow when you crank `k` up to 20 regardless of how they're written. As an exercise, try to speed it up, then check the solution thread to pick up ideas from others.

Comment: Thank's for the answer. I wrote that horrible function very late last night and somehow, the fact that the potential number should be divisible by ALL from 2 to 20 just didn't appear to me. Question: How does that middle value in the last for loop work? the one with the boolean value (!divisibleByAllBelowK(i, 10)) ?

Comment: No problem. That's the termination condition. The "divisible by all below `k`" function returns a boolean, so we keep iterating until it returns true.